# Core Spotlight subtitle attribute

Tags: corespotlight, nsuseractivity

Is there a list of content types -> attribute fields in CSSearchableItemAttributeSet that describe which attribute fields are used for the Spotlight search result subtitle?

Apple's example documents show multiple content attributes being used such as date created, date changed, etc but I couldn't find a mapping of which fields are actually considered for display.